# Image not align in a flex row

Tags: angular, css, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I have the following row in a mat-card-header:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px" fxFlex="1 1 100%">
        <div fxLayoutAlign="start" fxFlex="1 1 60%" >
          <h1 class="mat-title" color="accent">{{model.get_price()}}</h1>
        </div> 
        <div fxLayoutAlign="end" fxFlex="1 1 40%"><img mat-card-image class="card_cover_logo" src="{{model.image_path}}"></div> 
</div>
```

The result is the following:

[image]

The price and the image are not aligned. The image is higher than the text. Is there any flex directive to adjust that?

Comment: and what if you do `flex:0 0 x%` instead of `flex:1 1 x%`

Comment: ah i guess you need to make them both start or end `fxLayoutAlign="end"` actually they are different

Comment: start and end have a different meaning, I want to align them vertically not horizontally

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `align-items: center` on the parent element. Assuming the flex direction is row, this should align the items to their vertical center.